# Javascript nested map function return string

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a set of data. I map through my data, if data is `"HOME_DELIVERY` then it will go to another function which will check is the order is valid or not. if the order is valid then it will return `hello` string. So far everything works as expected but I want my map function return string `hello`. currently it's returning `['hello']`

```js
const getRoundName = (orderId) => {
  if (orderId === "a4013438-926f-4fdc-8f6a-a7aa402b40ea") {
    return "hello";
  } else {
    retrun
  }
};

const orders = [
  {
    id: "a4013438-926f-4fdc-8f6a-a7aa402b40ea",
    modifiedAt: "2022-02-28T09:26:18+00:00",
    deliveryDate: "2022-02-28",
    pickupLocation: null,
    orderStatus: "MODIFIED",
    deliverySlotId: "2022-02-28:66ee337c-e252-4297-9aed-cafcef396f19",
    createdAt: "2022-02-26T06:38:46+00:00",
    deliveryTime: "22-00",
    storeId: "516079340",
    orderNumber: 28354107,
    paymentMethod: "ON_DELIVERY",
    cartItems: [[Object], [Object], [Object]],
    deliveryMethod: "HOME_DELIVERY",
    additionalInfo: null,
  },
];

const roundName = orders.map((order) => {
  return order.deliveryMethod === 'HOME_DELIVERY' ? getRoundName(order.id) : ''
});

console.log(roundName);
```

Comment: nested? what is nested? a `.map` always returns an `array` with as many elements as the array you're mapping - there's no `nesting` happening

Comment: also  you have retrun in else

Comment: `.map()` returns an array based on the current array. You have an array with one item in it, therefore `.map()` returns an array with one item in it. If you *don't* want an array, then either don't map over one but directly use the first item or map and then take the first item. Or something along those lines.

Comment: If you have more than one order as `"HOME_DELIVERY"` in your data array, what are you expecting to see?

Comment: I have more than one order as "HOME_DELIVERY".  I want to get the result `string`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#return_value) returns an array as response. If you need a string as response, you have to modify the logic as

```js
const getRoundName = (orderId) => {
  if (orderId === "a4013438-926f-4fdc-8f6a-a7aa402b40ea") {
    return "hello";
  } else {
    return;
  }
};

const orders = [
  {
    id: "a4013438-926f-4fdc-8f6a-a7aa402b40ea",
    modifiedAt: "2022-02-28T09:26:18+00:00",
    deliveryDate: "2022-02-28",
    pickupLocation: null,
    orderStatus: "MODIFIED",
    deliverySlotId: "2022-02-28:66ee337c-e252-4297-9aed-cafcef396f19",
    createdAt: "2022-02-26T06:38:46+00:00",
    deliveryTime: "22-00",
    storeId: "516079340",
    orderNumber: 28354107,
    paymentMethod: "ON_DELIVERY",
    cartItems: [[Object], [Object], [Object]],
    deliveryMethod: "HOME_DELIVERY",
    additionalInfo: null,
  },
  {
    id: "a4013438-926f-4fdc-8f6a-a7aa402b40ef",
    modifiedAt: "2022-02-28T09:26:18+00:00",
    deliveryDate: "2022-02-28",
    pickupLocation: null,
    orderStatus: "MODIFIED",
    deliverySlotId: "2022-02-28:66ee337c-e252-4297-9aed-cafcef396f19",
    createdAt: "2022-02-26T06:38:46+00:00",
    deliveryTime: "22-00",
    storeId: "516079340",
    orderNumber: 28354107,
    paymentMethod: "ON_DELIVERY",
    cartItems: [[Object], [Object], [Object]],
    deliveryMethod: "HOME_DELIVERY",
    additionalInfo: null,
  },
];

const roundName = orders.flatMap((order) => {
  return order.deliveryMethod === 'HOME_DELIVERY' ? getRoundName(order.id) : ''
});

console.log(roundName.join(''));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter` before calling `map`

```
//if it has more than 1 items in the list, it will join them together like this `hellohellohello`
const orderIds = orders.filter((order) => order.deliveryMethod === 'HOME_DELIVERY').map(order => getRoundName(order.id)).join("")
```